# Info.plist error when importing flutter project into MacOS and running it

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I ran my flutter project but it gave me this error:

```
Error: unable to read property list from file: /Users/myname/Developer/appname/ios/Runner/Info.plist: 
The operation couldn't be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.)
```

This is my Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
    </array> 
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>apitesting</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <String>YES<String>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The app runs fine on VS Code via an Android Emulator but when I ran the project in Xcode, it gave this error. I made some edits myself when I had to configure it a little bit:

The LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and the "https, http, tel, mailto" that was added by me because I needed it for one of my packages.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the error. The dependency that I was using (WebView) made an error where they capitalized String when it should've been not capitalized. Also they forgot to put quotation marks around the YES string.